# Вживання інфінітивів з закінченнями "-ть" замість "-ти" (робити - роби́ть)

Tags: orthography, дієслова, дієвідмінювання

Дуже часто зустрічаю у вжитку інфінітиви (початкова форма дієслова), які вимовляють з закінченням `-ть` замість `-ти`:

> Робити - роби́ть
>   Співати - співать
>   Жити - жить
>   і т.д.

Приклади використання таких дієслів:

> Треба жити, як співати, а співать, як жить.
>   Тобі хочу я співать "алілуя".

Завжди цікавило, звідки пішла ця форма вжитку, наскільки розповсюджена така вимова і чи є така форма унормованою в сучасній українській мові?

Comment: З приводу «Розпрягайте, хлопци, коні» якось читав інтерв'ю, не пам'ятаю, з ким, але щось культурно-філологічного напрямку. Так от там говорили, що короткі закінчення інфінітиву «спочива**ть**», «копа**ть**» свідчать про східне походження тексту.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Відповідь тільки до частини запитання:

> чи є така форма унормованою в сучасній українській мові?

[Український правопис 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par83):

> § 83. НЕОЗНАЧЕНА ФОРМА ДІЄСЛОВА (ІНФІНІТИВ)
>
> **Неозначена форма дієслова закінчується на** **`-ти`**: *глибшати,
>   годувати, годуватися (годуватись), жити, кинути, лізти, нести, пекти,
>   пектися (пектись), ревти, ходити, хотіти*.
>
> Примітка 1. **В усному мовленні, а відповідно й у художній
>   літературі** іноді вживаються також скорочені форми інфінітива на
>   **`-ть`**, коли перед ним немає приголосного: *брать, казать, кинуть, терпіть, ходить.*

Проф. Ющук І.П. [ПРАКТИКУМ З ПРАВОПИСУ І ГРАМАТИКИ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ](http://educrimea.org/lib/books/Yushchuk.pdf)

> § 81. Неозначена форма дієслова. Минулий час. Умовний спосіб
>
> 1. **Неозначена форма дієслова** (що робити? що зробити?) **завжди закінчується суфіксом** **`-ти`**: *думати, працювати, боротися, радіти,допомогти*.
>
> Суфікс **`-ть`** **допускається лише в поезії та в розмовному стилі**: *Книга
>   вчить, як на світі жить.* (Нар. творчість.)